# C# gmail smtp AUTH LOGIN

Tags: c#, gmail

```
Socket soket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
soket.Connect("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);

string addToEnd= "\r\n";

byte[] dataBuffer;
string answer; 

NetworkStream netStream = new NetworkStream(soket);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(netStream);
answer = reader.ReadLine();

dataBuffer = BytesFromString("HELO Vlada" + addToEnd);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
answer = reader.ReadLine();

// NEXT CODE is for login but after that i get 502 5.5.1 Unrecognized command. i42si28816556eem.28

dataBuffer = BytesFromString("AUTH LOGIN someUsername" + dodatakNaKraju);
netStream.Write(dataBuffer,0,dataBuffer.Length);
answer = reader.ReadLine();
```

So it fails to login. The method `BytesFromString` just converts STRING to ASCII bytes.

I need it for exam.

Comment: Did you search for that error code online? What else have you tried?

Comment: Yea i did say that gmail use base64ENC. i try that with cmd windows/linus but i still fail

Comment: What is the `dodatakNaKraju` set to? Do you need to append your `addToEnd` string to this also?

Comment: yea that is it addToEnd is on Serbina dodatakNaKraju ;)